# How can I detect if a system is running inside a systemd-nspawn container?

Tags: container, systemd-nspawn

Quite recently I started using `systemd-nspawn` to set up other OS instances on my Arch box. One thing I'd like to do is detect if I'm inside a container, and if so, add the distro name (from `lsb_release`) to the terminal title. On Debian-based systems, the default `.bashrc` uses `debian_chroot` for a similar purpose. How do I detect if I am running inside a nspawn container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[systemd-detect-virt](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-detect-virt.html) can tell you whether your system is running in a VM/container. This requires systemd-detect-virt inside your container, but the systemd documentation on [minimal builds](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/MinimalBuilds/) suggests that you can just build a package that only includes systemd-detect-virt.

Comment: Excellent. Since I was using Debian 8, with systemd, for the container, `systemd-detect-virt` is just fine.